# Regex Match Except Hyphenated End-of-Line Words

Tags: regex, string, text, regex-lookarounds, text-processing

I want to match all words except words that end in a hyphen at the end of a line.  I want hyphenated words not at the end of a line to be matched.

```
>>> re.findall("[A-Za-z0-9']+(?!-$)","In-middle hyphens (yes) but shouldn't match hyphens at end-")
['In', 'middle', 'hyphens', 'yes', 'but', "shouldn't", 'match', 'hyphens', 'at', 'en']
```

The undesired behavior is the 'en' (last match).  I want 'at' to be the last match in this case.  I assume that this is a syllable split and I will count the word when it finishes on the next line.

Any ideas of how to make my regex "all-or-nothing" so that it won't match any letters from a word which ends in a hyphen at the end of a line?

Comment: Use word boundaries, `r"\b[A-Za-z0-9']+\b(?!-$)"`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZqSvY/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that might not suit my needs.  Word boundaries split up words with apostrophes.

Comment: Show me a case please.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was doing one very similar, but with a non-greedy '+'.  Yours does work for me, which is good.  Can you teach me why this method works, but my original did not?

Comment: Because of backtracking that `[A-Z...]+` allows and `(?!-$)` triggers. Word boundary requires a "word" border.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for sharing your knowledge!